# Update line text using Symfony Console (or PHP)

Tags: php, symfony, console, symfony-console

I want to make a console application that displays an user feedback for processes that runs for long time. Example:

```
Starting process
----------------

 - Task 1 (5mb)
 - Task 2 (7mb)
```

I want to update the *5mb* word without writing a new line, and continue to the next line when finished. I can't use a progress bar because I can't obtain a *total* before run the command...

Is there a way to do this with Symfony Console?

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for. Will try and post the results...